# boost.threads Singleton initialization

Tags: c++, boost, multithreading, singleton

Is there preferred way to initialize (lazily) singleton data when using multiple threads from boost.threads?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [call_once](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.once.call_once) free function in Boost.Thread.

Comment: You should check the answer anyway if it is the correct answer to your question.